# Setting gasPrice not working on private network

Tags: gas-price

I'm running geth with the following option:

```
--gasprice 21000
```

But if I execute the following command:

```
> eth.gasPrice
```

It gives me `20000000000`.

Comment: Why are you setting the gasprice to 21000?

Comment: It's just a random number. I'm running into a "VM create err: Contract creation code storage out of gas" when trying to deploy a contract, the first thing I've tried was to lower the gas price.

Comment: Ah, okay. 21000 happens to be the gas for a common transaction, so it seemed a bit odd

Answer (score 3):

The `--gasprice` flag sets the minimum price per gas that your miner will accept when mining transactions.

The `eth.gasPrice` command gives the current gas price, which is based off the moving averages of the gas prices sent in the last few blocks. This is not the same as the `--gasprice` flag.

Also, you may be confusing gas and gas price. Every simple transaction takes 21000 gas, regardless of the gas price. Setting the gas price may not be doing what you think it is.

Comment: I understand that. 21000 was a random number I've tried to put there. The problem is I'm running a clean install, on my own network, so the gasPrice should be set because there is no transactions mined at all, am I wrong?

Comment: No, eth.gasPrice defaults to 20 GWei, since that is what it is on the main net. It should adjust as transactions are mined

Comment: But I'm not running on the main net, I'm running on a private network, with my own network id and my own genesis block.

Comment: Yes, but the 20 GWei number is hard coded into the client

Comment: You don't need to use `eth.gasPrice` though, you can set gas manually with each transaction